# How initialization works of the super class constructor when calling the sub class constructor

Tags: java

say i have a parent class and a child class and call the constructor of the child class. Would I have to have both the child constructors arguments plus the parent constructors arguments and use super( ) to initialize the parent. And does this mean if i overloaded the parents constructor I would need to have constructors matching each of the child's constructors... So if I had two parent constructors

```
parent(int a);
parent(int a,int b);
```

and two child constructors

```
child(int c);
child(int c,int d);
```

I would have to have  child(int a) actually be in the form of two constructors

```
child(int a, int c) 
{
super(a)

c = this.c;
}
```

and

```
child ( int a, int b, int c)
{
super(a,b)

c = this.c;
 }
```

and have child(int c, int d) actually have two constructors

```
child(int a, int c, int d)
{
super(a);

c = this.c;
d = this.d;
}
```

or could i pass

```
child(int a,int b, int c, int d)
{
super(a,b);

c = this.c;
d = this.d;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The parent constructor is always invoked. If not explicit it will be implicit. Its up to you to define the parameters to invoke the parent constructor.

If parent doesn't present a default constructor (one that doesn't requires any parameter) you need to invoke it explicitly from you sub classes.

Nothing forbids you to have a general constructor as you commented in case of `child(int a, int b, int c, int d)` and invoke the parent class's constructor lie `super(a,b)`.

If you have some constructors on the parent class doesn't mean necessarily that you need to "propagate" them on the sub classes.

There is a good text regarding the constructor chaining [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_04.htm#INDEX-451).

Comment: if i explicitly call the parent constructor using super i would have to pass all it's arguments in the sub classes constructors?

Comment: @ChrisOkyen you need to get it from somewhere, for instance: if your parent class requires `(int a, int b)` and you need another parameter for your subclass you could write one constructor on your subClass like `(int a, int b, String c){super(a,b); this.c = c;}`. Another way is to generate this value (if it makes sense...) suppose the parameter a is always the same for that specific subClass, so you could do something like `(int b, String c) {super(3,b); this.c = c;}`

Comment: Thanks, it just seems really repetitive to have overloaded methods.

Comment: it just depends on your needs ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its up to you that how many overloaded version of construtor you want to write but keep in mind that every construtor of child class calls its super() with no arg implicitly if in parent no arg construtor is not there it will give you compile time error .but if yor are making in call explicitly you can call any supar construtor .